# Solr 7.5 JoinQueryParser with Muti Threaded Facet stops solr core with Exceptions

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are migrating from `solr 6.6` to `solr 7.5`. We have a solr Join which facets using facet. thread set to 32. We are seeing the repeated solrCore close exception and also further querying fails.Below are Exception stack trace. and solr Query

```
2019-07-09 17:37:30.053 INFO  (facetExecutor-67-thread-22-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [promotion_rules-v1_shard1_replica_n1]  **CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore**@44de0f89
2019-07-09 17:37:30.054 INFO  (facetExecutor-67-thread-22-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for registry=solr.core.promotion_rules-v1.shard1.replica_n1, tag=44de0f89
2019-07-09 17:37:30.056 INFO  (facetExecutor-67-thread-22-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.m.r.SolrJmxReporter Closing reporter [org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrJmxReporter@36a60356: rootName = null, domain = solr.core.promotion_rules-v1.shard1.replica_n1, service url = null, agent id = null] for registry solr.core.promotion_rules-v1.shard1.replica_n1 / com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@79be463d
2019-07-09 17:37:30.148 INFO  (facetExecutor-67-thread-22-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for registry=solr.collection.promotion_rules-v1.shard1.leader, tag=44de0f89
2019-07-09 17:37:30.159 INFO  (facetExecutor-67-thread-22-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.u.p.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory Triggering Graceful close of DocExpiration Executor
2019-07-09 17:38:03.062 **ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-26-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-4] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org**
2019-07-09 17:38:03.067 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-28-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] **o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-5] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org**
2019-07-09 17:38:06.176 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-25-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-7] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:38:07.602 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-24-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-6] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:38:11.868 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-23-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-8] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:38:32.522 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-4-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] **o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-9] on** org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:39:08.862 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-3-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-10] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:39:08.988 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-6-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-12] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:39:09.048 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-5-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-13] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:39:10.474 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-2-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-11] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:39:10.572 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-7-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-14] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
2019-07-09 17:39:10.646 ERROR (facetExecutor-67-thread-9-processing-n:127.0.0.1:8983_solr x:products_comp-v1_shard1_replica_n21 c:products_comp-v1 s:shard1 r:core_node22) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Too many close [count:-15] on org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@44de0f89. Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org
```

**SolrQuery**

```
q=*:*&defType=edismax&fl=comboid,skuid&start=0&rows=15&facet.limit=100&variant=A&debugQuery=true&debug.explain.structured=true&fq=!status_facet:inactive&fq=!mode:AF_ONLY&fq=**{!join+from=skuid+to=skuid+fromIndex=promotion_rules}id:promo-opera-test-1000_promo-opera-test-1000**&enableManagedResourceRange=true&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&**facet.threads=32**&facet.field=dynamiccategory_facet&facet.recommend.maxfacets=30&facet.recommend.debug=true&sort=ratingandreviewsort+desc&qt=/promo&timeAllowed=5000
```

Comment: Try the most recent version and if that doesn't help, do as the Exception says - `Please report this exception to solr-user@lucene.apache.org`

Comment: Did you face same issue. How  do you think latest solr will solve it?